# Migration from odoo 8 to 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Is there an easy way to migrate from odoo 8 to odoo 11?
I need to migrate from odoo 8 to 11 entreprise is there a way an easy one to do the migration fastly

Answer (score 0):

Usually your enterprise contract covers migrations. Just ask Odoo.

See:

- https://www.odoo.com/page/editions
- https://upgrade.odoo.com/database/upload

Answer (score 0):

For odoo 8-10 migration, you need to migrate databases and all the custom modules.

**1-For Database migration:**
You can use [OpenUpgrade](https://doc.therp.nl/openupgrade/migration_details.html) Script for database migration. You have to do manual migration using open-upgrade script. You can follow this [Blog](https://www.codemakeshare.com/?p=173) for database migration

**2- Custom Modules Migration:**
You have to resolve all the errors manually for views and modules migration.